# converting Pandas DataFrame to Excel sheet

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe of Cellphone names and prices, represented by df. I need to convert this dataframe to excel sheet.

Comment: Hey Saad, welcome to SO, this sort of question would (and as is the case here) you will get downvoted as it should be a simple google search. Were you not able to find anything via a search?

Answer (score 1):

Normally save it as a csv and open it in Excel but there is documentation on pandas to Excel
df1.to_excel("output.xlsx" sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Answer (score 1):

[I think `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` is what you are looking for.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)